# Python numerical integration and maximum solution of the equation

Tags: python, equation, numerical-integration

For given α≥0, let x_α be the maximum solution of the equation:

```
(np.sqrt(R**2-x**2))/(R**R + α**R) = np.log(R*(math.e)**(-R)*x+1)
```

Solve the equation: [Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DeTj.png)

I need a Python code for this. I don't know what means to find maximum x_α.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.